# How can I see which is my boot partition in latest suse 12 and 15 OS's?

Tags: boot, partition

In SLES 12 S, SLES15 it is observed that the OS can be installed and booted without creating a separate /boot partition. My question is how can we know which is my boot partition as I can't be able to search in df -ht command?